# Hessian of composite function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Let $\cal{J}(y) : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Furthermore, suppose $y := h(x)$ with the nonlinear mapping $h : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ twice differentiable. The Jacobian of $h$ is diagonal (i.e., $y_i = h_i(x_i)$ for all $i = 1 \ldots n$).

I want to calculate the second directional derivative of $J$ with respect to the variable $y$ along an arbitrary direction $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ - as a function of the second derivative of $J$ wrt $x$ (along $v$) and that of the mapping $h$.

The chain rule gives:

$$ 
\frac{\partial \cal J}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \cal J}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}.
$$

Here I'm following the standard convention (gradients = "row" vectors).

Then, I calculate the directional derivative of the (transposed) equation above - and things become a bit confusing...

$$ 
\frac{\partial \cal^2 J}{\partial x^2} \cdot v = \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)^T \left( \frac{\partial \cal^2 J}{\partial y^2} \right) \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right) \cdot v  + \left( \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} \otimes v \right)^T \left( \frac{\partial \cal J}{\partial y} \right)^T,
$$
where the $\otimes$ denotes the tensor-vector product operation.

Furthermore, suppose the Jacobian $\displaystyle \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ is non-singular over $\mathbb R^n$, and define
$$
\widehat{v} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \, v.
$$

Then:
$$
\frac{\partial \cal^2 J}{\partial y^2} \cdot \widehat{v} 
=
\left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)^{-T}  
\frac{\partial \cal^2 J}{\partial x^2} \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)^{-1} \widehat{v}
- \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)^{-T} 
\left( \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} \otimes \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)^{-1} \widehat{v} \right)^T \left( \frac{\partial \cal J}{\partial y} \right)^T.
$$

Does this look OK? The matrix dimensions seem to match up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this answers your question, to some extent at least.
Keeping track of all the matrices can be a nuisance, and I find it easier to operate with polynomials.

It is good to view this in terms of Taylor polynomials.
We have
$$
h(x+a)
=
h(x)+(Dh(x))a+\frac12(D^2h(x))(a,a)+O(|a|^3)
$$
where $D^2h(x)$ is a symmetric map $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$.
Similarly
$$
J(y+b)
=
J(y)+(DJ(y))b+\frac12(D^2J(y))(b,b)+O(|b|^3).
$$
Note that $h$ takes values in $\mathbb R^n$ and $J$ takes values in $\mathbb R$ although the expressions look the same.
Putting these together yields
$$
\begin{split}
J(h(x+a))
&=
J(h(x)+(Dh(x))a+\frac12(D^2h(x))(a,a)+O(|a|^3))
\\&=
J(h(x))+(DJ(h(x)))[(Dh(x))a+\frac12(D^2h(x))(a,a)]+\frac12(D^2J(h(x)))((Dh(x))a,(Dh(x))a)+O(|a|^3).
\end{split}
$$
But we should have
$$
J(h(x+a))
=
J\circ h(x)+(D(J\circ h)(x))a+\frac12(D^2(J\circ h)(x))(a,a)+O(|a|^3).
$$
These two polynomial expressions (ignoring the error term) must be equal for all $a$.
Comparing the terms gives first the chain rule
$$
(D(J\circ h)(x))
=
(DJ(h(x)))(Dh(x))
$$
and then for the second derivative
$$
(D^2(J\circ h)(x))(a,a)
=
(DJ(h(x)))(D^2h(x))(a,a)+(D^2J(h(x)))((Dh(x))a,(Dh(x))a).
$$
If $H_J(y)$ is the Hessian matrix of $J$ at $y$, then $(D^2J(y))(b,b)=b^TH_J(y)b$.
The second term of $D^2(J\circ h)$ corresponds to the matrix $Dh(x)^TH_J(h(x))Dh(x)$, but the first one cannot be written as neatly in matrix form.
With indices, we have
$$
(D^2(J\circ h)(x))(a,a)
=
\sum_{i,j,k}\partial_iJ(h(x))\partial_j\partial_kh_i(x)a_ja_k
+
\sum_{i,j,k,l}\partial_ih_j(x)\partial_j\partial_kJ(h(x))\partial_kh_l(x)a_ia_l
.
$$

Comment: thanks for the answer! I've made some further edits to my initial post. Your final equality seems to be equivalent to the 2nd to last equality from my post, unless I'm mistaken? (I have used the fact that the operator $D h(x)$ is diagonal so it commutes with the Hessian of $\cal J$ at $y$...)

Comment: @mishooax, it looks similar, but I'm not sure (yet) if it's the same. The Hessian of $J$ is not necessarily diagonal (unless I missed such an assumption) so it doesn't commute with all diagonal matrices. What do you mean by $\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} \otimes v$? Is it an $n\times n\times n$ "matrix" or something else? With suitable interpretation that term seems to be correct but I find the notation confusing. Once you need to go to tensors of higher order than two, writing things as matrix products can lead to ambiguities. Indices are more explicit but admittedly messy.

Comment: yes, you're right about $Dh(x)$ not commuting with the Hessian matrix, some confusion there on my part. The $\otimes$ indicates a tensor product between the 3-tensor Hessian $\partial^2 y / \partial x^2$ and the $n$-vector $v$.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta If I am not mistaken, the first term can be written in matrix form as $\sum\limits_i \partial_i J(h(x)) \sum \limits_{j, k} a_j \partial_j \partial_k h_i(x) a_k = a^t\left(\sum \limits_i \partial_i J(h(x)) D^2h_i(x)\right)a$.

Comment: @Dominik True! That form might indeed be easier to read. Unfortunately there is still a sum, but I don't see how to write it fully in a matrix-spirited but non-awkward way.